# Is this a correct usage of a semicolon

Tags: relative-clauses, semicolons

Directly from my paper

> It is therefore important to understand the source of V and its geochemical dynamics in these systems**; this** has not been extensively explored in the  literature

Or should I replace the semicolon with "which"

Comment: Looks fine to me, it replaces another conjunction such as "and".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently grammatically correct, and proper use of a semicolon, and it does make sense how it is. However, you may use ", which" in replacement of "; this" if you would like to emphasise the last clause a bit more.

Comment: Cheers for your help